# What is the default value for an uninitialized nested mapping?

Tags: solidity

What would the default value be for an uninitialized entry in the below mapping?

i.e. how to check if an address exists in the below mapping?

`mapping (address => mapping (bytes32 => uint256)) public someNestedMapping;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default for uninitialized storage slots (by the size of 32 bytes, aka a word) is always the 32 bytes of zeroes.

So to test if an address is part of the mapping you would check if

`someNestedMapping[yourAddress][yourBytes32] == 0`

Comment: Great - that helps a lot - thanks Richard.